# What is the purpose of asking whether a prospective grad student would attend the program in the absence of financial aid?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, application, funding

I need financial support to join a specific university. There is a question in the Master's application that says "Will you be willing to join the program even if you didn't receive financial aid? "

If I answered No to this question, would that mean that if I got accepted in the university but without financial aid I would receive a rejection letter from the university? 
If I answered Yes, would that decrease my chances in getting a financial aid?

Comment: (1) yes. (2) probably. Is it a tick-box, or  do you have a bit of space to give a one-sentence explanation?

Comment: It's a tick box

Comment: One way or the other, I advise you to answer honestly.

Comment: @aparente001 Definitely. Thank you for your advice. I just hoped there was a way I can still know the university's decision about my application regardless of the financial aid.

Comment: I don't think you can know that. Suppose they have X places but only Y scholarships. So they'd choose the top Y candidates for the scholarship and fill the rest with the best remaining candidates who agree to come without aid. If someone isn't chosen at round 1 but needs a scholarship, they won't even consider them at round 2, probably.

Comment: I have a family member who was accepted to a U.S. PhD program in a context like that, and they were basically milked for tuition indefinitely with no intention to graduate them, until they switched to a different program. So beware.